# how can I make these methods generic?

Tags: c#, generics, methods

What I have is some dictionaries that are all of the type

```
Dictionary<Guid, string>
```

I have a bunch of methods that basically do the same thing but use different parameters do filter various things.  Here are a couple sample methods

```
private IQueryable<SomeClass> FilterContacts(Filter filter,
        IQueryable<SomeClass> query)
    {
        if (filter.Contacts != null && filter.Contacts.Any())
        {
            result = result.Where(x => filter.Contacts.Contains(x.ContactID));
        }

        return result;
    }

private IQueryable<SomeClass> FilterSomethingElse(Filter filter,
        IQueryable<SomeClass> query)
    {
        if (filter.SomethingElse != null && filter.SomethingElse.Any())
        {
            result = result.Where(x => filter.SomethingElse.Contains(x.SomethingElseID));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

So they all these methods share the same structure but use different properties on the filter and in the where clause.  Is there a way to make this generic enough that I can just have one method that can do this?

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the strategy pattern.

Comment: Are the types of `Contacts` and `SomethingElse` etc all `Dictionary<Guid,string>`? Can you not just pass that in as a parameter rather than `Filter filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution uses a delegate as a parameter to inject some of the logic necessary to make the method more generic.

```
private IQueryable<SomeClass> FilterCommon(IQueryable<SomeClass> query
    , Filter filter
    , Func<Filter, Dictionary<Guid, string>> getDictionary
    , Func<SomeClass, Guid> getKey)
{
    IQueryable<SomeClass> result = null;
    Dictionary<Guid, string> commonDictionary = getDictionary(filter);
    if (commonDictionary != null && commonDictionary.Any())
    {
        result = query.Where(x => commonDictionary.ContainsKey(getKey(x)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

I don't think the Filter parameter is necessary so it can be simplified to this:

```
private IQueryable<SomeClass> FilterCommon(IQueryable<SomeClass> query
    , Dictionary<Guid, string> commonDictionary
    , Func<SomeClass,Guid> getKey)
{
    IQueryable<SomeClass> result = null;
    if (commonDictionary != null && commonDictionary.Any())
    {
        result = query.Where(x => commonDictionary.ContainsKey(getKey(x)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
//Initializing a few things first...
Filter myFilter = new Filter();
IQueryable<SomeClass> query = new Queryable();//Just a generated type

//This is for my first example from above
FilterCommon(query, myFilter, x => x.Contacts, x => x.ContactID);

//Second example without filter parameter
FilterCommon(query, myFilter.Contacts, x => x.ContactID);
FilterCommon(query, myFilter.SomethingElse, x => x.SomethingElseID);
```

Comment: this is more like I was thinking.  Let me see if I can make something work here with this.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy pattern seems appropriate in this case.

The strategy pattern allows you to define a family of interchangeable algorithms to be selected at runtime.  To define your algorithms you might do the following:

```
public interface IFilterStrategy<T> 
{
    IQueryable<T> Filter(Filter filter, IQueryable<T> query);
}

public class FilterContacts : IFilterStrategy<SomeClass>
{
     public IQueryable<T> Filter(Filter filter, IQueryable<T> query)
     {
        if (filter.Contacts != null && filter.Contacts.Any())
        {
            result = result.Where(x => filter.Contacts.Contains(x.ContactID));
        }

        return result;
     }
}


public class FilterSomethingElse : IFilterStrategy<SomeClass>
{
     public IQueryable<T> Filter(Filter filter, IQueryable<T> query)
     {
        if (filter.SomethingElse != null && filter.SomethingElse.Any())
        {
            result = result.Where(x => filter.SomethingElse.Contains(x.SomethingElseID));
        }
     }

}
```

How you would then implement this is dependent on the design and intended use of your class.  Some of these implementations are common:

1. Inject one or more strategies into the constructor at runtime
2. Allow the caller of your class's public method to pass an `IFilterStrategy<SomeClass>` instance
3. Maintain a private field of type `IFilterStrategy<SomeClass>` that you switch with a private set() method

In any case, you would maintain a single `Filter()` method in your actual class that would use the specified strategy pattern class.

Comment: sure this makes sense, but I thought there would be a nice simple way to do the filtering with one method rather than now having a bunch of classes that all implement the IFilterStrategy. Also I would have ~15 of these filters.

Comment: @MatthewTheTerrible Not sure if I get your question right but If all the filter.classes are some sort of collections why cant you pass the collections themselves and search on them or something like this :   private IQueryable<T> FilterContacts(Filter filter,
            dynamic someClass, string property)
        {
            var searchfrom = someClass.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(filter, null);